# How to display standard output in Mac application converted from shell script?

Tags: terminal, applications, automator, script

It's easy to convert a shell script to a Mac App as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30792569/converting-a-shell-script-into-a-app-file). But I am only able to see the operation result of the script(or the Mac App) after the script finished and there seem to be no easy way to see the standard output as we would do when launching the script in terminal. Currently I am directing the standard output to a text file and view the file with some editor like sublime text. But I don't like the way I am doing it and looking for some more decent way. Is there any chance I can launch a terminal to display the standard output?

Comment: If using a terminal to view the you don't want an app. Note that in a similar state Windows does not have stdout.  Gui apps jus do not generated text output to the user as you go along. If they do you add a wine in the gui. I am just not clear why you want a gui here.

Comment: @Mark Umm, all the effort made is to avoid using terminal to launch the script. I wrote the script for some non-terminal users. So I wrapped everything up in an app. That way they can just run the app and not be bothered by the terminal commands. However, at the same time, I want them to be able to see the output of the script, so they know how long they need to wait.